# How do I know if currently displayed chart data is grouped?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On HighStocks, how do I know if the currently displayed chart according to the selected period range data is grouped into weeks?

I am asking because I would like to set ToolTip text, saying "week starting..." once the data is grouped into weeks instead of days, so my question is what would be the js code to test whether or not the data displayed is grouped into weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to `currentDataGrouping` in series object, and here is structure, which should be helpful for you:

```
currentDataGrouping: {
    count: 1
    unitName: "week"
    unitRange: 604800000
}
```